# Removing rows/columns if one entry is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a python script that will run regularly and alert me if there is a change to prices on a website. I have gotten pretty far along in my newbie approach thanks to a lot of other posts but I have a little issue with the final hurdle.

I review the pandas documentation and found a few things that should have allowed me to remove the row that contained empty cells but I never got it to work.

```
pd.reset_option('max_rows')
pd.reset_option('max_columns')
pd.set_option('display.width', 800)
url="https://support.apple.com/de-de/mac/repair/service"
df = pd.read_html(url)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 0, 'display.max_columns', 3):

    df[0].replace(to_replace=r' €', value='', regex=True).replace(to_replace=r'^A.*', value='', regex=True).fillna(method='bfill').to_csv("mac0.csv", index = False)
```

Currently I am living with it but I feel like if I can get this to not print the empty rows it would allow me to apply the same technique to other websites I need to pull data off of.

An image of what I currently get as output: [as of posting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvWnU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas *dropna*:

```
df = df.dropna()
```

This method allow to drop (delete) cells with NaN elements. If the values are not NaN but things like empty string, 0s, or whatever, just use the *replace* method to put NaN in those cells:

```
df = df.replace(yourvalue, NaN) #maybe should be numpy.nan? check your libraries to see the syntax of nan values
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Read the docs for better understanding of this method, as it allow to drop rows where at least a element is missing, or if all of them are missing, or only if a value of certain column is missings.

Comment: I used dropna before and didn't the results I was looking for. When I added it to my script '''df[0].replace(to_replace=r' €', value='', regex=True).replace(to_replace=r'^A.*', value='', regex=True).fillna(method='bfill').dropna().to_csv("mac0.csv", index = False)''' it doesn't work. Can you show a screenshot of your output?

Comment: Sorry I don't have access right now to a computer with Python, I'll try to post it as soon as possible, but I don't know when could it be